# Will hover suggestions for java (any IDE) work if source code is not there but JavaDocs are shipped with the JAR?

Tags: java, ide, hover, javadoc

Will hover suggestions for java (any IDE) work if source code is not there but JavaDocs are shipped with the JAR?

I tried few things on VsCode:

1. Code refering to class from JAR with "source code" was showing hover suggestions.
2. Code refering to class from JAR with "no source" code but "attached Javadocs" was not showing hover suggestions.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am using vs-code. I have a java gradle project with dependencies. The depepenacy .jars having source-code, we can see javadocs in hover suggestions  when we are refering any class from those dependencies. When we don't have source-code but we have javdocs (html format) packed with the jar we see hover suggestion but not java-docs documentaion. 
Is it even possible to show hover javadoc when java source-code is not there but javdocs are packed inside the .jar? For any IDE intelliJ, eclipse? 

For vs-code I am using extension Language Support for Java(TM) by Red Hat.